# First time working with arduino, need help adapting project from UNO to NANO

Tags: arduino-nano, bluetooth, hc-05

This is my first time working with an arduino and I'm having some issues when trying to copy a program I found online on my Nano.

Basically, my project consists in a pulse sensor that sends the pulse information to the arduino and then to the hc-05 Bluetooth module so my phone can receive this information in real-time.

On my nano: D2 receives the output of the sensor, D8 and D9 are connected to pins RX/RT on HC05 and D13 has a LED connected to it.

Now here's the thing, I really don't know much about this and the code I found uses different pins from the ones I'm using.

The LED keeps blinking and isn't synchronized with the sensor output, when the led blinks I receive a response in the Bluetooth serial app but I would like to synchronize the heart sensor with the led so than I can receive the pulses on my phone. I've been trying to solve this but I still can't find a solution.

Full code can be found at 
https://www.instructables.com/id/Pulse-Sensor-With-Bluetooth-and-Arduino/

Here's part of my code

````
//bluetooth
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library

SoftwareSerial Genotronex(8, 9); // RX, TX
int ledpin=13; // led on D13 will show blink on / off
int BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer

//  Variables
int pulsePin = 2;                 // Pulse Sensor purple wire connected to analog pin 0
int blinkPin = 13;                // pin to blink led at each beat
int fadePin = 5;                  // pin to do fancy classy fading blink at each beat
int fadeRate = 0;                 // used to fade LED on with PWM on fadePin

// Volatile Variables, used in the interrupt service routine!
volatile int BPM;                   // int that holds raw Analog in 0. updated every 2mS
volatile int Signal;                // holds the incoming raw data
volatile int IBI = 600;             // int that holds the time interval between beats! Must be seeded! 
volatile boolean Pulse = false;     // "True" when User's live heartbeat is detected. "False" when not a "live beat". 
volatile boolean QS = false;        // becomes true when Arduoino finds a beat.

// Regards Serial OutPut  -- Set This Up to your needs
static boolean serialVisual = true;   // Set to 'false' by Default.  Re-set to 'true' to see Arduino Serial Monitor ASCII Visual Pulse 


void setup(){
  pinMode(blinkPin,OUTPUT);         // pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
  pinMode(fadePin,OUTPUT);          // pin that will fade to your heartbeat!
  Serial.begin(115200);             // we agree to talk fast!
  interruptSetup();                 // sets up to read Pulse Sensor signal every 2mS 
   // UN-COMMENT THE NEXT LINE IF YOU ARE POWERING The Pulse Sensor AT LOW VOLTAGE, 
   // AND APPLY THAT VOLTAGE TO THE A-REF PIN
//   analogReference(EXTERNAL);   
Genotronex.begin(9600);
  Genotronex.println("Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED ..");
  pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
}


//  Where the Magic Happens
void loop(){

    serialOutput() ;       

  if (QS == true){     //  A Heartbeat Was Found
                       // BPM and IBI have been Determined
                       // Quantified Self "QS" true when arduino finds a heartbeat
        digitalWrite(blinkPin,HIGH);     // Blink LED, we got a beat. 
        fadeRate = 255;         // Makes the LED Fade Effect Happen
                                // Set 'fadeRate' Variable to 255 to fade LED with pulse
        serialOutputWhenBeatHappens();   // A Beat Happened, Output that to serial.     
        QS = false;                      // reset the Quantified Self flag for next time    
       } 
      else { 

      digitalWrite(blinkPin,LOW);            // There is not beat, turn off pin 13 LED
      }

   ledFadeToBeat();                      // Makes the LED Fade Effect Happen 
  if (Genotronex.available()){
BluetoothData=Genotronex.read();
   if(BluetoothData=='1'){   // if number 1 pressed ....
   digitalWrite(ledpin,1);
   Genotronex.println("LED  On D12 ON ! ");
   }
  if (BluetoothData=='0'){// if number 0 pressed ....
  digitalWrite(ledpin,0);
   Genotronex.println("LED  On D12 Off ! ");
  }
}
  delay(20);                             //  take a break
}```
````

Comment: why do you believe that synchonizing an LED with the sensor will actually send the pulses to the phone?

Comment: Because everytime the led blinks I receive it as a pulse on the phone

Comment: to port a sketch from Uno to Nano do: nothing

Comment: @Ricardo, the pulse transmit action causes the LED to flash, not the other way around .... what you want to do is for the pulse to be transmitted every time the sensor gets triggered ... the LED is irrelevant

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What should the LED do in relation to what? Also: Can you post the complete code. There are missing some function implementations, that might be important for whatever you want.

Comment: @chrisl the led on D13 should blink everytime the arduino receives a pulse from D2.  The complete code is in the link, I don't know how to post multiple tabs here. Basically I'm having trouble with changing the pins in the code to use it on my nano, everything should remain the same.

Comment: @jsotola Yes, you're right

Comment: @juraj all I need to do is change the pins from the original program so it works with my arduino nano, I know that's super easy, but I'm stuck

Comment: The original code uses PIN A0 to receive the output from the sensor, I'm using D2. I replaced the 0 for a 2 in the variable pulsePin, but still the arduino wont receive the pulse information, in my phone I get random pulses but they're not coming from the sensor.

Comment: you can't use pin 2. the sketch uses analogRead which works only on A pins. if you changed it to 2, then it is A2. why did you change the pin?

Comment: @juraj I changed it to pin A0 and it worked fine!! I still would like to know how to change it from A0 to D2. I really have no idea and already switched analogRead to digitalRead but it didn't work, also, thank you :)

Comment: for analogRead the pin have to be analog. I don't know why analogRead is used here

Answer (score 0):

First: There is no need to change pin assingments, when changing from Uno to Nano. They use the same microcontroller and have the same pins.

You have set `pulsePin` to 2, which corresponds to pin D2. But the pulse sensor gives you an analog signal. D2 is not capable of measuring analog voltages, it can only measure digital voltages. Meaning you need to use one of the analog pins, A0 to A7, so use one of these pins in the declaration of `pulsePin`.

The reason for this is, that the microcontroller uses an extra peripheral device included in it for measuring analog voltages: the ADC (Analog to Digital Converter). It can only be connected to a limited number of pins (internally via a multiplexer). That also means, that you can only measure the analog voltage at one pin at a time.